# How to create multiple Windows file extensions with different descriptions but identical actions?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-registry, file-association, file-types

In Windows 7, is it possible to have different file extensions with unique description names, but all the same actions, without duplicating all the actions (for each extension) in the Windows registry?

As a simple contrived example, have these file extensions and descriptions:

```
File extension: .txt 
Description: "Text File"

File extension: .no
Description: "No Way"

File extension: .yes
Description: "Absolutely"
```

By "Description", I'm referring to the description that Windows displays in the Type column in Windows Explorer & native open/save dialog boxes.

With all three extensions having identical open, edit, print, printtto, et. al. context menu commands (actions).

This is trivial to accomplish if you are okay with all the descriptive names being the same for all the extensions, but that is not what I want.

I'm fine manually editing the Windows registry to get this accomplished.

Note that I would prefer to avoid "User Choice" overrides, but if that's a requirement to get this done, so be it.

Answer (score 1):

Create the file type at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\my_yes_file` normally, then create the `shell` subkey as a *symbolic link* pointing to `\MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\txtfile\shell`.

Windows supports symlinks in the Registry through [the API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regcreatekeyexw) but the standard tools cannot create them; you'll need third-party software (as described in [this blog post](https://scorpiosoftware.net/2020/07/17/creating-registry-links/)).

Searching GitHub found [CreateRegSymlink.ps1](https://github.com/rweijnen/Posh-Snippets/blob/906cc4e415e65eadd74dae9375096dccfe31a04c/CreateRegSymLink.ps1) (a C# program pretending to be a PowerShell script) and [mkreglink](https://github.com/gabriellandau/mkreglink).

Comment: I hate this solution but I bet that it is the only way to possibly do what he is asking for.

Comment: Symlinks in the registry?  Such power I didn't know was available!  Is this how the default aliased registry hives work?

Comment: @RockPaperLz: It seems that HKCU and HKCR aren't done through symlinking, they (and the rest of HKEY_*) work as a whole different layer of illusion, probably similar in concept to how "drive letters" are done. On the other hand, some keys such as CurrentControlSet (mentioned in the linked blog post) do use symlinks; [RegExp](https://github.com/zodiacon/RegExp) shows a few more.

Comment: Thanks for the details and also the link to RegExp.  Are you the author by any chance?  Either way, you may like this tool as well: https://registry-finder.com

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the actions once and use them for multiple extensions,
each extension keeping its own other settings.

You would give this common action a name and store the data under that name:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
-- myname
---- open
------ command
---- print
------ command
```

Your extensions will use `myname` this way:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
-- .txt
---- (Default) is myname
-- .no
---- (Default) is myname
```

Each extension can have its own other data.

Comment: This won't do what he is asking for as the descriptions are stored in the target of .ext -> default and not under .ext itself.  He is asking how to have unique descriptions for each extension without duplicating the target action (like txtfile).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: He *is* asking to duplicate the actions, just not the rest of it: "With all three extensions having identical open, edit, print, printtto, et. al. context menu commands (actions)."

Comment: Harry, you are correct that I do want to duplicate the actions... but where would I put the unique description names for each extension ("Text File", "No Way", and "Absolutely" in the example)?

Comment: Anywhere you like - create a new `reg_sz` item below `.txt` etc, call it for example `Description`, and set its value. It would have no meaning for Windows and so won't bother anything.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm referring to the actual description that Windows displays in the `Type` column in Windows Explorer & native open/save dialog boxes.  That's what I would like to be unique for each extension, but with the actions shared amongst a large group of extensions.

Comment: That won't work with a common action, so for that you will need to duplicate the actions in each extension. Early Windows versions used to have an item named `FriendlyTypeName` which contained the description. But later versions replaced this with the lousy dual-nature of the `(Default)` item, which can contain either a type-description or pointer to a common action. Today, all entries where is found `FriendlyTypeName` are required to be the same as `(Default)`. See randomly `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\smpFile`.

Comment: See `FriendlyTypeName` in the following links: (1) [Programmatic Identifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-progids), (2) [How to Register a File Type for a New Application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-register-a-file-type-for-a-new-application). In other words: The Type column contains the handling application, it is not a description.